# Setting table cell widths with css not working

Tags: html, css

I have simple table I am trying to style with CSS.  The problem is that I cannot get the table cell widths to work.  Here is my code:

```
table {
border: 1px solid lightgray;
border-spacing: 0px; 
table-layout: fixed;

}

td.name {
padding: 0;
background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
width:'80px';
}



table.myclass {  border: solid lightgray 1px;
}

<table class="myclass">
<tr>
<td class="name"><input type="checkbox"></td>
<td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png">Name</td>
<td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png">Report Type</td>
<td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png">Modified On</td>
<td class="name"><img class="line" src="line.png">Description</td>
</tr></table>
```

When I render this, the table cell widths all exactly fit their content.  They are not 80 pixels as I have tried to achieve. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No quotes in `width:'80px';`. Should be `width:80px;`

Answer (score 0):

You must set the table ***width*** too, if that doesn't work, set **overflow: hidden;** in the *td* style as well.

Comment: thanks.  when i entered width: 1200px; then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

i think the value shouldn't be inside the quotes '80px' but 80px :

```
td.name {
padding: 0;
background-color: rgb(245,245,245);
width:80px;
}
```

Comment: The quotes don't matter

Comment: @eyp - yes, they absolutely do.

Comment: no man i think they matter and i test it it work without quotes

Comment: Ok, my mistake, don't hit me ;)